# Selecting pages by path in MySQL/SQLite databases

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sqlite

I am storing pages for websites in a 'pages' database table, they are referenced by their path (i.e. 'articles/my-first-blog-post'), I need to select all the children of a particular page, but without selecting grandchildren.

So if I run:

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE path LIKE 'articles%'
```

I'll get pages with the following paths:

```
articles/one
articles/two
articles/two/more
articles/three
articles/three/more/even-more
```

I need to filter them (in the query) to just:

```
articles/one
articles/two
articles/three
```

Is there anyway to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE path LIKE 'articles%' AND path NOT LIKE 'articles%/%'
```

Any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for that. The keyword `REGEXP` works both for [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) and [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#binaryops):

```
... WHERE path REGEXP '^articles/[^/]+'
```

Comment: This seems like the best way, but I'm getting the following error:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: REGEXP

Do I need to install an addon or something? I'm using Mac OS Snow Leopard, SQLite is just for dev, MySQL for production, so if it's just an addon that's no problem.

Comment: Looks like I just need an addon for the Ruby implementation. Your suggestion worked perfectly, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question in the first place, Ryan. I am experiencing the same problem with REGEXP not being recognized. What addon did you have to install? How? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your files have file extensions this will work:

```
   SELECT * FROM pages 
    WHERE path LIKE 'articles%' 
      AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,'/',2) LIKE '%.file_extension';
```

otherwise:

```
   SELECT * FROM pages 
    WHERE path LIKE 'articles%' 
      AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,'/',2)=SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,'/',3)=;
```

Comment: This would have worked, apart from I'd have to calculate the number of forward slashes each time, so it's more complicated than the regexp suggestion. Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions (LIKE clause or REGEXP) may incur severe performance problems in SQLite because they require full table scan. Read more about this in http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html.

You can use inequality operators (like < and >) to increase performance (if the relevant column has an index).

Comment: I only use SQLite for development, MySQL in production, so this isn't an issue. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: In the future, please do not post a "signature" or your website URL in your answers, or they (and your account) risk being deleted as spam. Your signature is already included on your posts, and your website URL is on your profile. I am editing these for you so future readers do not think you were trying to spam.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE path LIKE "%/%" AND path NOT LIKE "%/%/%";
```

works for me at least.